# How can I uniquely identify a device with unchanging identity?

Tags: php, authentication, web-applications, device, fingerprinting

I am developing a PHP web application. I want users to sign in with the same device that they used for registration and restrict the users coming with a different device. So, I need a device fingerprint method that does not change often. While using a device fingerprint system to authenticate the user, the user should not disappointed with the system due to general changes from the client side such as software updates, changing the browser, or clearing history and cookies.

Google and Facebook show our device information and they can perfectly say this is the device last I logged in. I need a method something like that.

I have searched this in Google, Bard, Chat GPT, and Stack Overflow. But I didn't get the right answer. I cannot use the User Agent or localStorage because they can be changed in some situations. I need a device ID such as a MAC address, but I got to know that it is not possible.

Comment: Perhaps you can narrow it down it a bit more? When you say: "device", do you mean mobile phones, desktops, or both?

Comment: I mean it for all the devices like desktop, tablet, and mobile.

Comment: Uniquely identifying all possible devices, through a web browser alone, is not feasible. Regrettably you never mentioned why you want to employ this restriction, making it hard for us to come up with an alternative suggestions. For instance, allowing to log in, on only one device at the same time, is a good option, if you don't want multiple user using the same account.

Comment: "Google and Facebook show our device information and they can perfectly say this is the device last I logged in" - Are you sure? If you log in using a private browsing window, does it still recognize your exact device? For me I have to go through full reauthentication.

Comment: "I cannot use the User Agent or localStorage because they can be changed in some situations" - as to local storage, are you worried about a person registering on device ABC, then going to device XYZ and manually copy and pasting the information into localStorage, thus bypassing? I don't know the reason behind your need for this device lockdown, but that seems like a very exceptional case to me.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, let's get Netflix. If any person buys an account and then shares it with friends, there is a loss to Netflix. My client wants end-users not to share one account with their friends. So, the problem arrived. What to do if the end-user deletes the localStorage data from his/her computer or mobile? That is why I came up with this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I don't want the end-user to share his account with his friend. Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: As I said before, you could start with only allowing one active user per account. Whether this will be effective depends on how long, and when, users want to log into the service. For instance, two users, who share an account, might want to watch Netflix in the evening, but they're not allowed to both log in at the same time. That would be quite a restriction. However, if users only need to log in 5 minutes every 2 days, then this isn't a restriction at all.

Comment: @AadhilAhamed, thank you very much for the example, that really helps us. We have seen many people asking for what you are doing, but it turns out they are trying to solve another problem. Your scenario makes total sense.

Comment: For something like Netflix, I don't know if they have a web interface anymore, but for their apps they have access to actual device IDs for exactly this purpose. For something web-based I think you are really limited to stashing something in local storage and then storing some additional fingerprint information such as IP address and maybe UA in your database. Then, upon login you might have to perform some heuristics to determine how similar that information is to allow device upgrades and roaming but balanced with your "I think you are a different person".

Comment: If someone does log in successfully, but their additional fingerprint doesn't match (or match enough), then just invalidate the old information, maybe prompt for secondary confirmation and consider this new device as the only valid one.

Comment: You could also consider to require [2 Factor Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication). For a simple example of how this could work [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h000FgWyKJA). The trick is that only one specific mobile phone, the one belonging to the user, can validate the login. You cannot easily share it, although your friend could call you when a pass code is needed. I've implemented this several times, and it does restrict things quite a bit. It also increases security. Implementing it means first wrapping your head around how this works.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, although I don't disagree with that, I actually print out every QR code from my TOTP setups and store them in a secure location which allows me to add them back in some time in the future if I ever lose my device. Back before Google's authenticator supported syncing that was how I migrated to a different tool. So a user just needs to send the QR code to whomever once and they can use it. Using a pushed-based MFA might be better, although someone could still just call their friend and ask for it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas True, there are ways around this type of 2FA. You could work with codes send by e-mail, but again, a mail-box can be shared. Something like an [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) seems an option.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is : You can't !

For the privacy and security matters, you're not allowed to access user device other than standard ways like IP, user agent, cookie, session, etc. But if your users are willing to install some extension or app, you may have a chance to control their device more accurately.

No need to say that expertise users still can easily manipulate your code from their side, and even Google or Facebook can't control users behavior this much, and you can simply change your user agent to show them different device.